# Пикселизация изображения после рендера

Tags: c#, unity3d

Каким образом можно достичь эффекта укрупнения пикселей полученного рендера перед тем, как вывести его на экран?

Допустим, в моей 3д игре определённое количество раз в секунду все 3д пространство перед камерой рендерится в изображение, которое отображается на экране. Однако мне нужно, что бы перед его отображением я мог это изображение обработать, а точнее, применить к нему эффект укрупнения пикселей. Что бы это выглядело примерно так:

[image: Такой рендер]

[image: Вот что выводится на экран]

Вроде бы, в это делается с помощью пиксельных шейдеров. Но ведь в юнити нельзя создать пиксельный шейдр. И как тогда это сделать?

Comment: [раз](http://www.reddit.com/r/Unity3D/comments/20arg7/i_made_a_script_to_make_a_unity_camera_render/), [два](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/making-a-local-pixelation-image-effect-shader.183210/), [три](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/16314), [четыре](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/33558), [пять](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/14252),  [шесть](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/18433), [семь](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/935). Можно найти еще варианты.

Answer (score 1):

Такой эффект применяется при постобработке. Берут картинку и делают ее меньше, а потом просто растягивают на полный объем. Вместо растягивания можно сделать копирование одной точки в прямоугольный сектор. Посмотрите как сделан [Blur](http://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/Manual/script-Blur.html).